# How to: Create and manage layouts?

Tags: c#, windows, monogame

I am trying to learn something and create really simple thing like `Menu`. But, there is one thing. I worked once in [construct](/questions/tagged/construct). It has really nice "Layouts" management. It looked like: `If (pressed new game) {move to Game_Layout}`, on created earlier layouts, then instead of drawing `Menu_Layout`, `Game_Layout` was drawn. I could add `Equipment_Layout`, and `Options_Layout`, and so on, with simple moving between them.

In [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) on the other hand I found really nice sample [here](https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples/tree/master/XNAPacMan), which includes such thing, but in a bit difficult way for me. I managed to recreate code for Windows, and compile, but I think there must be something easier. The problem is all tutorials about "how to menu" uses simple "if else" statement, without additional cs files, which is terrible (in comparison with CartBlanche).

So, there are my questions:
Is there easier way to achieve such thing?

If not, about what should I learn, to use it efficiently (`Game.Services` for example)?

Maybe someone faced such problem before and can share with tutorial about this?

Thank You for all Your time, even for reading this.

Comment: Question is too broad. You have to create your own layout management.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric Does full management is needed? In mentioned by me sample there is something, what works like "replacing", override probably?
And, if I have 3 *cs files, each with Update and Draw functions, cannot I just override func from 1st *cs by func from 2nd *cs?